Как добавить словосочетание в список Python
Вопрос:
Функция должна распечатать список продуктов. На вход функции поступает произвольное количество значений. Продуктом считается любая непустая строка. Любые другие типы данных (списки, числа и так далее) нужно проигнорировать. Напечатать список продуктов необходимо в следующем виде:
Пример
Код:
print_products('печенье', 'хлеб', 'молоко')

Вывод:

печенье
хлеб
молоко
Если в переданных значениях не встретится ни одного продукта, то распечатайте: "Нет продуктов".

Проблема: если входные данные [],1234,{},блины,шоколадные батончики, то на выходе получаю 1. блины.
А нужно:
1. блины 
2. шоколадные батончики. 

Проблема именно в словосочетании "шоколадные батончики". Подскажите, как реализовать добавление словосочетания?
#Код
args = input().split(",")

def print_products(*args):
    products = []
    for arg in args:
        if isinstance(arg, str) and arg.strip():
            if arg.strip().isalpha() or arg.strip().isspace():
                products.append(arg)

    if products:
        for i, product in enumerate(products, 1):
            print('{}. {}'.format(i, product))
    else:
        print("Нет продуктов")

print_products(*args)


Метод str.isalnum возвращает false в случае, если в строке встречаются любые неалфавитные символы. В вашем случае это пробел между 2 словами

@ЮрычBRO, что-то я не понимаю... мне этот метод нужно использовать для решения проблемы? Или Вы опечатались? У меня используется сейчас метод isalpha(), а с методом str.isalnum будут выведены еще цифры, которые мне не нужны здесь

Да, опечатался, должно было быть isalpha, но ни тот ни другой использовать не нужно

разделите строку еще раз по пробелу, и проверьте все части isalpha

for arg in args:
    words = arg.split(" ")
    if all(word.isalpha() for word in words):
        products.append(arg)


Проверка каждого символа на принадлежность к набору допустимых
args = input().split(",")

def print_products(*args):
    products = []
    for i in args:
        for character in i:
            if character.lower() not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю ":
                continue
        products.append(i)


Если вам помог ответ, нажмите галочку, чтобы принять ответ

этот вариант также не работает, как задумано...Если сейчас передать данные: [],1234,{},блины,шоколадные батончики, на выходе будет: 1. []
2. 1234
3. {}
4. блины
5. шоколадные батончики А спецсимволы и цифры не должны выводится. Может все-таки метод какой-то нужен?

Можно через regex (модуль re). Модифицирую ответ сейчас

мне этот модуль еще не знаком... не подскажите, каким еще образом это можно решить?

можно проверять каждый символ каждой строки. Что то вроде if character.lower() not in "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmйцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбю ": ...

уже обновил ответ, конечно, код для вывода результата сами добавите. Вообще вопрос странный, ибо непустая строка может содержать любые символы, а не только алфавитные и 0. И все, что получено из input().split() должно подходить.

такое задание дано... но предложенное исправление, также не работает.... в любом случае спасибо, буду додумывать дальше
